# Multiple elements with multiple event handlers passing parameters; d3.js; simplify code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, event-handling

How can I generate these event handlers dynamically ? I would like to have this as a single statement that loops over element.length.

```
    d3.select("#wordcloud_0_im").on("click", function(d,i)
    {
        var x =1;
        wordclouds(keyfile,start=(x-1)*wordcount,stop=x*wordcount);
    })
    d3.select("#wordcloud_1_im").on("click", function(d,i)
    {
        var x =2;
        wordclouds(keyfile,start=(x-1)*wordcount,stop=x*wordcount);
    })
    d3.select("#wordcloud_2_im").on("click", function(d,i)
   {
        var x =3;
        wordclouds(keyfile,start=(x-1)*wordcount,stop=x*wordcount);
    })
```

I am not sure about how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
   function handleElement(i) {
        document.getElementById('wordcloud_' + i + '_im').onclick=function(d,e) {
            wordcount = 40;
            x=i;
            console.log("x :" + x);
            wordclouds(keyfile,start=(x-1)*wordcount,stop=x*wordcount);

        };
    }

     for(i=1; i<35; i++) 
        handleElement(i);
```